# Aptana 3 autocomplete with Zend Framework PHTML files

Tags: zend-framework, autocomplete, php, aptana3

Is there a way to make autocomplete feature work in Aptana 3 with the .phtml files in Zend Framework, it works fine with .php files but not with .phtml?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the file type and associate it with an editor.

Goto Window->Preferences->General->Editor->File Association.

1. In the File Types section, click [Add...] and enter *.phtml.
2. Select the file type that you just added.
3. In the Associated Editor section, click [Add...]. Select the
   PHP source editor.

Comment: Have you also added the Zend Framework to Aptana Studio->Editors->PHP->Libraries?